# Call `FnOnce` from `Fn`

Tags: javascript, rust, closures, future, n-api

I'm working with two different libraries (specifically [`napi-rs`](https://napi.rs/) and [`callback-future`](https://crates.io/crates/callback-future)) and want to invoke a `FnOnce` function from one library in a `Fn` function from another. Specifically, I'm trying to expose a Rust function to JavaScript which completes a `Future` when invoked.

Since the exposed JS function can technically be captured and invoked at any time, there is no way for Rust to guarantee that the function will only be called once, so it has to assume that the function will be called many times. However, `callback-future` requires that a `Future` is only completed once (via invoking an `FnOnce`). I can't modify these two signatures, and they are both accurate for their respective use cases. How can I get the two to work together so I can resolve a `Future` in a `Fn` callback?

I understand that it's not ok to invoke the `FnOnce` multiple times, and I'm ok with using `unsafe` code or otherwise enforcing at runtime that the function is only called once. Subsequent invocation attempts can be detected and rejected before calling the `FnOnce`, but I'm not sure how to communicate to the Rust compiler that I'm doing this and that it's ok to allow the call to `FnOnce`. Currently what I have is:

```rust
// Create a `CallbackFuture` to wait for JS to respond.
// `complete` is an `FnOnce` to mark the `Future` as "Ready".
CallbackFuture::<Result<String, Error>>::new(move |complete| {
  thread_safe_js_function.call(Ok(Args {
    // Other arguments...

    // Callback for JS to invoke when done.
    // `Fn` because JS could theoretically call this multiple times,
    // though that shouldn't be allowed anyways.
    callback: Box::new(move |ctx| {
      let result = ctx.get::<JsString>(0)?.into_utf8()?.as_str()?.to_owned();

      // Complete the `Future` with the result.
      complete(Ok(result));

      ctx.env.get_undefined() // Return `undefined` to JS.
    }),
  }), ThreadsafeFunctionCallMode::Blocking);
}).await
```

This gives me the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `complete`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
   --> node/src/lib.rs:368:15
    |
352 |           CallbackFuture::<Result<PathBuf, Error<BundleErrorKind>>>::new(move |complete| {
    |                                                                                -------- captured outer variable
...
358 |               callback: Box::new(move |ctx| {
    |  ________________________________-
...   |
368 | |               complete(Ok(result));
    | |               ^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `complete` has type `std::boxed::Box<dyn FnOnce(Result<PathBuf, Error>) + Send>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
369 | |     
370 | |               ctx.env.get_undefined()
371 | |             }),
    | |_____________- captured by this `Fn` closure

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

While the error is complaining about moving between closures, my understanding is that this isn't allowed because `complete` is `FnOnce` and I'm trying to call it from an `Fn`. If there's another approach which solves the closure issue, then I guess that could be a viable solution too.

Also if there's a way in N-API to accept a `Promise` result and `await` it instead of going through a callback, that could be a great alternative as well. I believe you can `await` a `Promise` in Rust, but AFAICT there's no way to receive a synchronous result from a threadsafe N-API function as `napi-rs` seems to [ignore the return value](https://github.com/napi-rs/napi-rs/blob/548f358fdbaeba43be4a91aaec3b411a404ffb61/crates/napi/src/threadsafe_function.rs#L400).

So far, the only solution I've found is to fork the `callback-future` API to change `complete` from an `FnOnce` to an `Fn`, which obviously isn't a great solution. I also tried `std::mem::transmute()` from `FnOnce` to `Fn` thinking that forcing a cast that way would work as long as I only called the function once. However doing so segfaulted when invoked, so I don't think it works the way I want it to here. Any ideas here are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably need to wrap `complete` in Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>`, and then `.take()` the `Option` value inside the callback, something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d44155c633b29644924d436d8b2a2eb0 (not tested as there's no self contained example in the question).

Comment: @Dogbert If I'm not mistaken, the `Arc` layer is unnecessary; it could just be `Mutex<Option<_>>`, no?

Comment: @cdhowie I think you're right. A `Mutex` should be enough for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have an example we can compile ourselves and there is some missing detail, I will address the heart of your question: how do you call an `FnOnce` from an `Fn`?

The first problem you already know: if you try to call the `FnOnce` directly, this is disallowed because it consumes the value, which would make the calling closure itself `FnOnce`, but you need an `Fn`.

The second is that if you try to use something like `Option` with its `take()` method, you'll find that `Fn` can't mutate its captured state (it would have to be `FnMut` to do that).

The solution is to wrap an `Option` in a type providing interior mutability.  Depending on whether you need your `Fn` to also be `Send + Sync`, you could use either `Cell` or `Mutex`.

With `Cell`, which is *not* `Send + Sync`, it would look something like this:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn print_owned(x: String) {
    println!("print_owned called with {:?}", x);
}

fn call_twice(f: impl Fn()) {
    f();
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let foo = "foo".to_string();
    let fnonce = move || print_owned(foo);
    
    let maybe_fnonce = Cell::new(Some(fnonce));
    
    call_twice(move || {
        match maybe_fnonce.take() {
            Some(inner) => inner(),
            None => println!("maybe_fnonce is None"),
        }
    });
}
```

When the closure passed to `call_twice()` invokes `take()` on the `Cell`, the inner value is extracted and replaced with `None`.  If the function is called again, the inner value will be the `None` previously put there.  This also means you can detect this situation and possibly signal the problem back to the JavaScript side.

If the closure needs to be `Send + Sync` then you can instead use `Mutex<Option<_>>`:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn print_owned(x: String) {
    println!("print_owned called with {:?}", x);
}

fn call_twice(f: impl Fn()) {
    f();
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let foo = "foo".to_string();
    let fnonce = move || print_owned(foo);
    
    let maybe_fnonce = Mutex::new(Some(fnonce));
    
    call_twice(move || {
        match maybe_fnonce.lock().unwrap().take() {
            Some(inner) => inner(),
            None => println!("maybe_fnonce is None"),
        }
    });
}
```

All you need to do is apply this technique to your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. This is exactly what I needed. `Cell` was sufficient in this case since this particular segment is all on the same thread, so I didn't need `Send + Sync`.

Comment: @DouglasParker Nice, that's the perfect solution then since `Cell` has no runtime overhead!